# one while loop to count up and down

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, python-3.7, countdown

How do you write a program to count up and down from a users integer input, using only one while loop and no for or if statements?

I have been successful in counting up but can't seem to figure out how to count down. It needs to look like a sideways triangle also, with spaces before the number (equal to the number being printed).

this is my code so far;

```
n = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
i = " "
lines = 0
while lines <= n-1: 
    print(i * lines + str(lines))
    lines += 1
```

Comment: Always tag your questions with their language, they will get more views that way.

Comment: You just need another while loop with `while lines >= 0` and in the loop `lines -= 1`

Comment: I can't add another while loop for the exercise. Can only use one

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this by making good use of negative numbers and the absolute value: `abs()` which will allow you to "switch directions" as the initial number passes zero:

```
n = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
s = " "
i = n * -1

while i <= n: 
    num = n - abs(i)

    print(s * num + str(num))
    i += 1
```

This will produce:

```
Enter an integer: 3
0
 1
  2
   3
  2
 1
0
```

Comment: I hadn't though of that, thank you! this was so helpful! How about if you wanted to count up and down but not print the input?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by not print the input. Do you mean count up to one less than than the input? If so, just subtract one from the input: `n = int(input("Enter an integer: ")) -1`

Answer (score 0):

Move the print line to after the `while` loop.  Form a list of lists (or an array) in the `while` loop using the content from your current print statement.  Then create a second statement in your single `while` loop to count down, which creates a second list of lists.  Now you can sequentially print your two lists of lists.